# azure pipeline cron not run

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

[image]

[image]

#### Why isn't cron running every two minutes

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
schedules:
- cron: '0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *'
  displayName: success
  branches:
    include: master
  always: true
```

When I use a cron generator to evaluate your cron string it errors which leads me to believe the issue is due to a bad cron string.

Here is the tool I used: [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Comment: Quartz based cron is different to regular Unix based cron - different numbers of args, etc. Azure appears to use a 5 args Unix cron engine, not the 7 args based Quartz engine.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't cron running every two minutes

The cron syntax `*/2 * * * *` should be work.

I test it with github resource and your cron syntax:

[image]

And the result:

[image]

So, I can sure your cron syntax `*/2 * * * *` is correct. We need to check other aspects， like:

- Check the modification of schedules in the `.yml` file is synchronized to the github repo.
- Create a new pipeline for the `success.yml` without any other settings.

If above not help you, you could try to create a pipeline for the Azure devops repo instead of the github rrpo with same cron syntax to check if you still have this issue, so that we could narrow the scope of this issue.